# How to do Jquery Animation Floating Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I recently have been trying to use Jquery to create and html animation and I am trying to make a bar float to the right as it is currently floated to the left. Although when I try to do this it wont work please help

Html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".bar").animate({float: 'right'});
    });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" align="center" >
      <div class="obj">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="body">
          <h1> Welcome </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css :

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  font-family:Raleway;
}
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;

}
.obj {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:14%;
}
.bar {
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  width:5px;
  background-color:#95a5a6;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.body {
  width:495px;
  height:200px;
  float:right;
}
.body > h1 {
  font-size:70px;
  color:#333;
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: You cannot animate the `float` property. Your best alternative would be to make the element `position: absolute` and then animate the `left` and/or `right` position of it. I would imagine this will take a fair amount of re-working of your HTML though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Alright thanks for the help man I will make sure to look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the position like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.bar').animate({"left" : 700 +'px'});

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZpbaP